# Can you voluntarily suppress damage resistance?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance

I have **Resist 10 Fire**.

I get hit for 13 points of fire damage, so normally, under these circumstances, I'd take 3 points of fire damage.

What if, because of another ability that triggers on becoming bloodied, I really want to take the full amount of fire damage and become bloodied?

Do I have that option? Can I voluntarily suppress the damage resistance? If I can't suppress it, can I end it in a way that lets me take that damage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**,

There is no mention of anything in the rules that would allow that.  So I'd have to disallow it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I expected, but I vaguely remembered some rule from 3.5 that let you do that...

Comment: @yhw42 - I know you could lower your spell resistance in 3.5  Not sure about other resistances.